# Sets & Propositions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $A, B$ and $C$ be sets. If $a$ is the proposition $x\in A$, $b$ is the proposition $x\in B$, and $c$ is the proposition $x\in C$, write down a proposition involving $a, b$ and $c$ that is logically
equivalent to $$x \in A \cup (B − C).$$

Attempt: $a\cup (b \cap \neg c)$. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Please show your attempt at the question.

Comment: Your attempt looks good. More appropriate notation: $a\vee[b\wedge\neg c]$ (the symbols $\cup$ and $\cap$ linked with sets are now $\vee$ and $\wedge$ linked with logic).

Comment: oh okay! thank you! does is matter if i use the square or round brackets too?

Comment: @Okie For me it would not matter. Depends on what your teacher thinks of it. Further it is a good thing to go for notation that is commonly accepted.

Answer (score 1):

$\cup$ and $\cap$ are operations on *sets*, but you want operations on *propositions*, so you want to use $\lor$ and $\land$. In fact, you already figured out to use $\neg$ as an operation on a claim, rather than to stick to $B-C$ or, equivalently, $B \cap C'$.

So, you should use $a \lor (b \land \neg c)$

Answer (score 0):

Use $\land$ and $\lor$ for the logical connectors, $\lnot$ for not etc.

Then your idea is essentially correct but I'd write

$$a \lor (b \land \lnot c)$$

Logically this is the same as

$$a \lor \lnot(b \to c)$$

so that's one alternative that looks less trivial.